# DC.js histogram of crossfilter dimension counts

Tags: crossfilter, dc.js

I have a crossfilter with the following data structure being inputted.

```
project | subproject | cost
data = [
["PrA", "SubPr1", 100],
["PrA", "SubPr2", 150],
["PrA", "SubPr3", 100],
["PrB", "SubPr4", 300],
["PrB", "SubPr5", 500],
["PrC", "SubPr6", 450]]
```

I can create a barchart that has the summed cost per project:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data)
var projDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.project;});
var projGroup = costDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.budget;});
```

What I want to do is create a dc.js histogram by project cost...so {450: 2, 300: 1}, etc. As far as I can tell, crossfilter can have only attributes of each row be input for a dimension. Is there a way around this?

Comment: benlaird, if you found an answer, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: Histograms in dc.js require a second grouping. My solution currently is to not use dc.js for the histogram. Instead, I use crossfilter to group and then d3 to create a histogram (which does not require the values to be grouped).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting the challenge!

It is true, crossfilter does not support this kind of double-reduction, but if you are willing to accept a slight loss of efficiency, you can create "fake dimensions" and "[fake groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted)" with the desired behavior.  Luckily, dc.js doesn't use very much of the crossfilter API, so you don't have to implement too many methods.

The first part of the trick is to duplicate the dimension and group so that the new dimension and old dimension will each observe filtering on the other.

The second part is to create the fake groups and dimensions, which walk the bins of the copied group and rebin and refilter based on the values instead of the keys.

A start of a general solution is below.  For some charts it is also necessary to implement `group.top()`, and it is usually okay to just forward that to `group.all()`.

```
function values_dimension(dim, group) {
    return {
        filter: function(v) {
            if(v !== null)
                throw new Error("don't know how to do this!");
            return dim.filter(null);
        },
        filterFunction: function(f) {
            var f2 = [];
            group.all().forEach(function(kv) {
                if(f(kv.value))
                    f2.push(kv.key);
            });
            dim.filterFunction(function(k) {
                return f2.indexOf(k) >= 0;
            });
            return this;
        }
    };
}

function values_group(group) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            var byv = [];
            group.all().forEach(function(kv) {
                if(kv.value === 0)
                    return;
                byv[kv.value] = (byv[kv.value] || 0) + 1;
            });
            var all2 = [];
            byv.forEach(function(d, i) {
                all2.push({key: i, value: d});
            });
            return all2;
        }
    };
}

// duplicate the dimension & group so each will observe filtering on the other
var projDim2 = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.project;});
var projGroup2 = projDim2.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.budget;});
var countBudgetDim = values_dimension(projDim2, projGroup2),
    countBudgetGroup = values_group(projGroup2);
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/55zf7L1L/

Answer (score 1):

[image] [JSFillde Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z0nzvt09/)

Denormalize + Map-reduce. Note the data already include the cost per project as the 4th column ( and this can be pre-calculated easily). It's a hack, but hopefully an easy one in order to get DC.js and crossfilter works without too much change.

```
var data = [
    ["PrA", "SubPr1", 100, 450],
    ["PrA", "SubPr2", 150, 450],
    ["PrA", "SubPr3", 200, 450],
    ["PrB", "SubPr4", 300, 800],
    ["PrB", "SubPr5", 500, 800],
    ["PrC", "SubPr6", 450, 450]
];

var newdata = data.map(function (d) {
    return {
        project: d[0],
        subproject: d[1],
        budget: d[2],
        cost: d[3]
    };
})

var ndx = crossfilter(newdata),
    costDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.cost;
    }),

    visitedProj = {},
    costGroup = costDim.group().reduce(function (p, v) {

        if (visitedProj[v.project]) return p;
        console.info(v.project);
        visitedProj[v.project] = true;
        return p + 1;
    }, null, function () {
        return 0;
    });

dc.rowChart("#costChart")
    .renderLabel(true)
    .dimension(costDim)
    .group(costGroup)
    .xAxis().ticks(2);

dc.renderAll();
```

Map-Reduce can be very powerful and the API can be accessed from [here](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference).  [JSFillde Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z0nzvt09/)

Comment: leoh, could you elaborate? Is there a way to combine these two dimensions? This doesn't seem to be an answer as-is.

Comment: sure, the idea being the map-reduce, I have updated my answer with a simple demo using the sample data originally provided in the question.

Comment: That's not quite what ben and I are asking about. We want to first group by project and then group by cost. Doing each individually is straightforward.

To reiterate from ben's question:
What I want to do is create a dc.js histogram by project cost...so {450: 2, 300: 1}

Comment: Now I remember the original answer I posted. Sorry it took me a while to get that back. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Hm. This hack doesn't integrate with crossfilter (see my comment in the bounty). Suppose we filter out subpr2. None of the numbers in the histogram update correctly.

Comment: This hack is integrated with crossfilter (click the cost bar at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7djpgwzf/) . It just the subproj is not a dimension that will affect the project cost, as it's being precaculated. if you want to filter on subpr2 and make the proj cost changed dynamically, you might need to extend the crossfilter, likely the dimension method. Hope the answer help the original question, if not the bounty.