# Making DCJS histogram based on the calculated average

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a long format data like following.

```
year company value
2001 AAAAAAA 200
2002 AAAAAAA 300
2003 AAAAAAA 400
2001 BBBBBBB 150
2002 BBBBBBB 250
2000 CCCCCCC 500
2001 CCCCCCC 600
2002 CCCCCCC 550
```

Is it possible to calculate the `average` of `income` by each `company`, then make a histogram by calculated `average` on DC.js?

What I first did was to make dimension by `company` and calculate average, then tried to make `average` as the `key`.

Problem I faced there was that if you tried to make histogram out of that, you have to `reduceCount` it by `average` dimension. But of course the `average` does not exist on the `crossfilter` object.

This is my jsfiddle script.
http://jsfiddle.net/adamist521/n1383zdk/3/
Final image of the graph is also included in script.

Probably related to this one but couldn't figure out how to deal with non-integer average.
[DC.js histogram of crossfilter dimension counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989510/dc-js-histogram-of-crossfilter-dimension-counts?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a running average (Crossfilter is about running calculations) you need to keep track of both the sum and count. Once you have these, calculating the average is trivial. In fact, you should not calculate averages in Crossfilter at all, but just track the components. You need to use a custom group for this to track both count and sum on the same group.

There is an example of just such a custom group in the Crossfilter documentation at: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order

In your dc.js chart, you would then define a valueAccessor to calculate the average at time of display:

```
chart.
  ...
  .valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value.total/d.value.count; })
```

Comment: What would the `key` be? I want to make histogram by average...  
ex. X-Axis: average(450, 500, 550, ... ) , Y-Axis: count(10, 20, 30, ...)

Comment: If you want to make a histogram by average on each record, then create a dimension based on the average (either include the average on your records or use a dimension accessor that calculates the average).