# Histogram based on "reduceSummed" groups

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have CSV data with the following pattern:

```
Quarter,productCategory,unitsSold
2018-01-01,A,21766
2018-01-01,B,10076
2018-01-01,C,4060
2018-04-01,A,27014
2018-04-01,B,12219
2018-04-01,C,4740
2018-07-01,A,29503
2018-07-01,B,13020
2018-07-01,C,5549
2018-10-01,A,3796
2018-10-01,B,15110
2018-10-01,C,6137
2019-01-01,A,25008
2019-01-01,B,11655
2019-01-01,C,4630
2019-04-01,A,31633
2019-04-01,B,14837
2019-04-01,C,5863
2019-07-01,A,33813
2019-07-01,B,15442
2019-07-01,C,6293
2019-10-01,A,35732
2019-10-01,B,19482
2019-10-01,C,6841
```

As you can see, there are 3 product categories sold every day. I can make a histogram and count how many Quarters are involved per bin of unitsSold. The problem here is that every Quarter is counted separately. What I would like is a histogram where the bins of unitsSold are already grouped with a reduceSum on the Quarter.

This would result in something like this:

```
Quarter, unitsSold
2018-01-01,35902
2018-04-01,43973
2018-07-01,48072
2018-10-01,25043
2019-01-01,41293
2019-04-01,52333
2019-07-01,55548
2019-10-01,62055
```

Where, based on the bins of unitsSold, a number of Quarters would fall into. For example a bin of 50.000 - 70.000 would count 3 Quarters (2019-04-01, 2019-07-01 and 2019-10-01)

Normally I would do something like this:

```
const histogramChart = new dc.BarChart('#histogram');
const histogramDim = ndx.dimension(d => Math.round(d.unitsSold / binSize) * binSize);
const histogramGroup = histogramDim.group().reduceCount();
```

But in the desired situation the histogram is kind of created on something that has already been "reducedSummed". Ending up in a barchart histogram like this (data does not match with this example):

[image: Histogram with a number of "Units sold" bins and the number of "Quarters" that fall in to them]

How can this be done with dc.js/crossfilter.js?

Comment: I tried it with the other example, but I just can't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regrouping the data by value

I think the major difference between your question and [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989510/dc-js-histogram-of-crossfilter-dimension-counts) is that you want to bin the data when you "regroup" it. (Sometimes this is called a "double reduce"... no clear names for this stuff.)

Here's one way to do that, using an offset and width:

```
function regroup(group, width, offset = 0) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      const bins = {};
      group.all().forEach(({key, value}) => {
        const bin = Math.floor((value - offset) / width);
        bins[bin] = (bins[bin] || 0) + 1;
      });
      return Object.entries(bins).map(
        ([bin, count]) => ({key: bin*width + offset, value: count}));
    }
  }
}
```

What we do here is loop through the original group and

1. map each value to its bin number
2. increment the count for that bin number, or start at 1
3. map the bins back to original numbers, with counts

#### Testing it out

I displayed your original data with the following chart (too lazy to figure out quarters, although I think it's not hard with recent D3):

```
const quarterDim = cf.dimension(({Quarter}) => Quarter),
    unitsGroup = quarterDim.group().reduceSum(({unitsSold}) => unitsSold);

quarterChart.width(300)
    .height(200)
  .margins({left: 50, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20})
    .dimension(quarterDim)
  .group(unitsGroup)
  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([d3.min(data, d => d.Quarter), d3.timeMonth.offset(d3.max(data, d => d.Quarter), 3)]))
  .elasticY(true)
  .xUnits(d3.timeMonths);
```

and the new chart with

```
const rg = regroup(unitsGroup, 10000);
countQuartersChart.width(500)
  .height(200)
  .dimension({})
  .group(rg)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear())
  .xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(10000))
  .elasticX(true)
  .elasticY(true);
```

(Note the empty dimension, which disables filtering. Filtering may be possible but you have to map back to the original dimension keys so I’m skipping that for now.)

Here are the charts I get, which look correct at a glance:

[image: double-reduced charts]

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7f1wuh0/13/).

#### Adding filtering to the chart

To implement filtering on this "number of quarters by values" histogram, first let's enable filtering between the by-values chart and the quarters chart by putting the by-values chart on its own dimension:

```
const quarterDim2 = cf.dimension(({Quarter}) => Quarter),
    unitsGroup2 = quarterDim2.group().reduceSum(({unitsSold}) => unitsSold);
const byvaluesGroup = regroup(unitsGroup2, 10000);
countQuartersChart.width(500)
    .height(200)
  .dimension(quarterDim2)
  .group(byvaluesGroup)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear())
  .xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(10000))
  .elasticX(true)
  .elasticY(true);
```

Then, we implement filtering with

```
countQuartersChart.filterHandler((dimension, filters) => {
  if(filters.length === 0)
    dimension.filter(null);
  else {
    console.assert(filters.length === 1 && filters[0].filterType === 'RangedFilter');
    const range = filters[0];
    const included_quarters = unitsGroup2.all()
        .filter(({value}) => range[0] <= value && value < range[1])
        .map(({key}) => key.getTime());
    dimension.filterFunction(k => included_quarters.includes(k.getTime()));
  }
  return filters;
});
```

This finds all quarters in `unitsGroup2` that have a value which falls in the range. Then it sets the dimension's filter to accept only the dates of those quarters.

#### Odds and ends

##### Quarters

D3 supports quarters with [interval.every](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/main/README.md#interval_every):

```
const quarterInterval = d3.timeMonth.every(3);

chart.xUnits(quarterInterval.range);
```

##### Eliminating the zeroth bin

As discussed in the comments, when other charts have filters active, there may end up being many quarters with less than 10000 units sold, resulting in a very tall zero bar which distorts the chart.

The zeroth bin can be removed with

```
  delete bins[0];
```

before the return in `regroup()`

##### Rounding the by-values brush

If snapping to the bars is desired, you can enable it with

```
.round(x => Math.round(x/10000)*10000)
```

Otherwise, the filtered range can start or end inside of a bar, and  [the way the bars are colored when brushed is somewhat inaccurate](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/520) as seen below.

[image: with filtering and quarters]

[Here's the new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/p49L1axv/56/).

Comment: Thanks! It works like a Swiss clock. Like you already mentioned, the filtering is disabled.

Comment: It actualy works when filtering on the productCategory, but not on the rest (time groups). Can you add the solution for filtering, so it actually behaves like it would have been a normal/single reduced histogram?

Comment: update: also filtering of the productCategory gives strange behavior. So indeed, filtering is not implemented yet :-)

Comment: It should filter okay based on other charts. Just make sure you are using a different dimension on those charts because [a group does not observe its own dimension’s filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters). So you may need two time dimensions. My comment above is that it would be hard to implement filtering based on selections in *this* chart. “Weird behavior” is not descriptive… pretty sure you will find it is doing what follows from your dimension/group definitions. ;-)

Comment: I take the exact code from your example and use a different dimension for the regroup chart. When I filter via another chart, for example on year then this happens: 1. the bin directly after 0 is filled with all the quarters. And there are some bins where you can see a very vertically small bar. In the transition it initially seems like the bars are going to the right direction, but then goes to this situation.

Comment: Yes, please do the math and think about the affects on the charts. When filtering causes all the quarters to have small numbers, then there will be many quarters with a small number. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/d2647fsh/3/) looks correct to me.

Comment: I agree, but where does that first bin (direct after 0) then come from. In my case there are 100 quarters that fall into that first bin, and makes the bars in the others bins of course (relatively) very small. If I can get rid of that first bar (with 100 quarters) it should be ok. What happens when filtering on a chart which is grouped by quarter?

Comment: I seems like it's behaves like a rest bin. The more years I select, the lower that first bar (after 0 on the x axis) gets. And what goes off there, seems to be added to the other (normal) bars.

Comment: You could remove the lowest bin e.g. with `delete bin[0]` before the `return`. It’s often confusing when a chart doesn’t contain all of the data, but you could do that. Like I said, I think it is doing what you asked for, whether that’s what you want is another story. :-D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233650/discussion-between-marc8932-and-gordon).

Comment: Updated answer with filtering and a few other things.

Comment: Hi @Marc8932, did this work for you? Please accept the answer if so.

Comment: It works great @Gordon, thanks for the clear explanation and example!